# C# If – else – if ladder Statement with Expression Trees

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I am new to expression trees and I am confused as to whether an If-Else-If ladder statement can be created using expression trees.  I see a lot of examples for If-Else statements, but nothing that extends past that.  Maybe it is obvious how to extend the If-Else example to If-Else-If, but I just don't see it.

The reason I want to do this is I want to give my end users the ability to write and store business rule into a **database** that I can retrieve at run-time and evaluate the rule.  At the moment there is **no limit** to how big the ladder can be meaning there could be multiple else if conditions.

Maybe there is a better way to do this?

My primary use case is the following logic, but it needs to be configurable to add further conditions.

```
if(isNumeric(Result) == false)
{
    if(Result == ">")
    {   
        return "HIGH";
    }
} 
If(Result > UpperLimit)
{
    return "FAIL";
}
else if((Result <= UpperLimit)&&(Result >= LowerLimit))
{
    return "PASS";
}
else if(Result <  LowerLimit)
{
     return "ABNORMAL";
}
else 
{  
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Dynamic expressions?  That would work.  Or you could use CodeDOM and code-generate explicit fixed code that isn't subject to evaluation

Comment: I will have to research dynamic expressions some I have never heard of them

Comment: It is what you already mentioned. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries

Comment: Ok I guess I don't understand how to extend it to my use case.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Sounds like a good opportunity for scripting. Let the user feed you some javascript/vbscript and execute it.

Comment: @MickyD No this is not homework.

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams Scripting will not work do to the performance, this was my first choice.  Scripts are taking to long to execute.

Comment: @SteveS OK, then the next best thing would be to allow the user to compile a dll and then have your code dynamically invoke functions there-in. The user will be responsible for writing the code, compiling the code and putting it in a location that your program has access to. Then you'll have the speed of compiled code - but it does require your end users to be a little more technical. Of course, it sounds like your users need to know how to program already.